# How can I cut wood in a very awkward location?

Tags: wood, kitchen-counters

I recently installed a new kitchen sink and faucet. It was one of those with the spot for a dish detergent pump.

After getting everything in, I come to find out there just isn't enough room to fit the bottle for the pump.

What I need to do is cut about 2 inches of wood that is about 1/2 inch thick, however, it's in a very awkward position.

Are there any suggestions on what I could use to cut?

Comment: A picture might help

Comment: @gregmac - I'll see want I can do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have enough room to use an electric drill with a 2" [hole saw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_saw)?  If not, perhaps a [Dremel](http://www.dremel.com) or similar tool with a routing bit?

Comment: I do have enough room. I also have a Dremel. The hole saw might work, I was focused on something the that cut down or across and in.

Answer (score 4):

Keyhole saw might be your friend here.   I actually have one where I broke MOST of the handle off so it fits smaller spaces :)  For those in need, here is a picture of one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_saw

Answer (score 3):

Like @Niall I would first recommend a Dremel tool (if you don't have one or can't borrow one, it's a sound investment for any DIYer's toolbox!).

Alternatively, a [new oscillating tool by Bosch](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=202564945&langId=-1&catalogId=10053) is made specifically for small, hard-to-reach jobs like this.  You might want to check that out as well.

Comment: I actually have a Dremel rotary and a multi-max (oscillating). The problem I had with the oscillating was I created more a friction fire than actual cutting LOL. I'll definitely try the routing bit.

Answer (score 2):

If there's enough space to tap a hammer you could also try a chisel. I've found myself getting out the chisel now and then for tight situations.

Comment: A great "less power" solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, there wasn't enough swing space for a hammer.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but a Oscillating Power Tool has been my go to for most for the awkward jobs.